# How do i get memory usage of specific application just like it show in the windows task manager?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public static void getallmemoryusage(string processName)
{
    Process[] pprocessName = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);//.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
    var counter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Working Set - Private", processName);
    privateMemeory = string.Format("Private memory: {0}k", counter.NextValue() / 1024);
}
```

Some problems here:

1. I have a variable Process[] pprocessName but i never use it.
2. The it is now i'm getting a value that is not the same one in the task manager.

In the task manager i see 192.6MB in my program i see 197232.
Now i started playing the game use the application(process) now in task manager it show: 219.0MB in my program 224304.

Why it's now the same values and what should i do with the Process[] pprocessName variable ?
Also how do i show the percentage/s for the application(process) like it show it in task manager ?

I want that this method will return the same value of memory usage and same percentage value like in the task manager.

Comment: One MB = 1024 KB, 1 KB = 1024  bytes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JEDEC_memory_standards#Unit_prefixes_for_semiconductor_storage_capacity

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# calculate CPU usage for a specific application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277556/c-sharp-calculate-cpu-usage-for-a-specific-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. You can get the physical amount of memory occupied by each through the `WorkingSet64` property of th `Process` class.

[MSDN says:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.process.workingset64)

> The amount of physical memory, in bytes, allocated for the associated
>   process.

In your case `pprocessName` is the array of processes with the name "processName"
So you can do:

```
foreach(var process in pprocessName)
{
  var memoryBytes = process.WorkingSet64;
  //...
}
```