# Is it always bad to use Thread.Sleep()?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sleep

I created an extension method for the the class `Random` which executes an `Action` (void delegate) at random times:

```
public static class RandomExtension
{
    private static bool _isAlive;
    private static Task _executer;

    public static void ExecuteRandomAsync(this Random random, int min, int max, int minDuration, Action action)
    {
        Task outerTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            _isAlive = true;
            _executer = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { ExecuteRandom(min, max, action); });
            Thread.Sleep(minDuration);
            StopExecuter();
        });
    }

    private static void StopExecuter()
    {
        _isAlive = false;
        _executer.Wait();

        _executer.Dispose();
        _executer = null;
    }

    private static void ExecuteRandom(int min, int max, Action action)
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        while (_isAlive)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(random.Next(min, max));
            action();
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine.

But is the use of `Thread.Sleep()` in this example okay, or should you generally never use `Thread.Sleep()`, what complications could occur ? Are there alternatives?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Is using `Thread.Sleep` bad? Generally not, if you really want to suspend the *thread*. But in this case you don't want to suspend the *thread*, you want to suspend the *task*.

So in this case, you should use:

```
await Task.Delay(minDuration);
```

This will not suspend the entire thread, but just the single task you want to suspend. All other tasks on the same thread can continue running.

Comment: I don't understand what the difference is, isn't a task just a managed thread? Thread.Sleep() also only blocks the current task, else I wouldn't work.

Comment: No, they are not the same. [What is the difference between task and thread?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4130194/993547)

Comment: If you don't `await` on `Task.Delay`, you're not really doing anything at all.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov you are right of course. Added for clarity. The action should be `async` too then to allow `await`.

Comment: What happens in Task.Delay(), doesn't it also use something like Thread.Sleep() inside?

Comment: No, what happens if one thread runs multiple tasks. With `Thread.Sleep` you will suspend all, not just one.

Comment: simple explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082221/when-to-use-task-delay-when-to-use-thread-sleep

Comment: *All other tasks on the same thread can continue running.* But he's creating a dedicated thread to run this task. I'm not sure why that makes a difference?

Comment: Keep in mind, that if your application is GUI based rather than a console application, the OS (or window manager) will be expecting the thread to do other things than just your process your code. Specifically, it expects the main thread to handle messages pumped to it for things like mouse events, control processing, and other housekeeping things.  It typically does these things while it is idle, but sleeping isn't considered idle.  If your thread doesn't respond to these messages the OS, window manager, or user may think it locked up.

Comment: Only time I used thread.sleep was to pause the thread while a web socket thread was starting, so it would wait before returning a response to the browser.  This is a good example of pausing a thread.

Comment: @NightSkyCode why couldn't you await that?

Answer (score 8):

One reason I would use `Task.Delay` over `Thread.Sleep` is the fact that you can pass a `CancellationToken` to it. If the user wants to `StopExecutor` and the random received a long duration span, you'll end up blocking for a long time. On the other hand, in `Task.Delay`, you can cancel the operation and it will be notified of that cancellation.

I think there are other problems with the design you choose to make. The `Random` class isn't really *fit* to be a task scheduler. I would find it a bit odd to find a `ExecuteRandomAsync`, since it mostly doesn't execute a random, but execute some arbitrary `Action` every X minutes.

I would instead, go about this another way. While keeping most of the internals you've already created, but putting them in a different class.

```
public class ActionInvoker
{
    private readonly Action _actionToInvoke;

    public ActionInvoker(Action actionToInvoke)
    {
        _actionToInvoke = actionToInvoke;
        _cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    }

    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;
    private Task _executer;

    public void Start(int min, int max, int minDuration)
    {
        if (_executer != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        _executer = Task.Factory.StartNew(
                    async () => await ExecuteRandomAsync(min, max, _actionToInvoke),
                    _cancellationTokenSource.Token, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, 
                    TaskScheduler.Default)
                    .Unwrap();
    }

    private void Stop()
    {
        try
        {
            _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException e)
        {
            // Log the cancellation.
        }
    }

    private async Task ExecuteRandomAsync(int min, int max, Action action)
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        while (!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(random.Next(min, max), _cancellationTokenSource.Token);
            action();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the duration implemented?

Comment: @Berntonline You don't need to sleep twice.

Answer (score 7):

`Sleep` "talks" to the Operation System that you want to suspend the thread. It's resource-intensive operation cause your thread uses RAM anyway (although it doesn't require processing time).

With thread pool, you could use thread's resources (f.e. RAM) to process some other small tasks. To do it, the Windows lets you put a thread to **sleep** in a special alertable state, so it may be awakened and used temporarily.

So `Task.Delay` let you put threads to alertable sleep, and therefore let you use resources of these thread unitl you don't need them.

Answer (score 4):

Think of it this way.

Sleeping a thread is dangerous because more often than not more than one tasks relies on that thread, not to mention key components of the program may do also. 
Never using `sleep` on threads isn't appropriate, you will want to use them when they are beneficial to your program.

Lots of people are taught not to sleep threads because of the unpredictable behaviour. It's like managing a team, eventually you're going to have to let some go to lunch and as long as the rest are functioning whilst the ones you chose to go to lunch are out, then you should be fine and be able to work still.

Just don't send people to lunch if there's people in the project reliant on their presence.

Comment: Well, is it beneficial is this example, or should I use something else?

Comment: @PatrickHofman has delved into the alternatives to entire thread sleeping... though there is no real alternative to real thread sleeps than to solve the problem with other measures (outside threading, or inside your logic).

Answer (score 0):

All answers are correct, and I would like to add a practical view:

When you have a remote non real-time component to test (for example, a search engine), you need to give it time to go to it's new state before you reference it again for assertions. In other words, you want to suspend your test for some time. Since the performance the test itself is irrelevant (please distinguish between the performance of the **test** and the performance of the **component**), you sometimes prefer to keep your **code** (of the test) as simple and straight forward as possible, and you avoid even the minimum complexity of asynchronous code. You could of course start a new test instead of waiting for your component (that's the difference between `await Task.Delay()` and `Thread.Sleep()`), but the assumption was that you are in a no hurry for that.