# How to get the CPU usage performance counter for one of the same running processes (multiple instances)?

Tags: c#, windows, process, cpu-usage, performancecounter

I am using multiple instance of a program like `Notepad.exe` thus n-instances of it the same time.

I wanted to create a performance counter so that it will give the CPU utilization for each process.

The number of running instances of notepad is dynamic.

I tried all the approach but did not find a way how to track multiple instances of same process to get the stats.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# calculate CPU usage for a specific application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277556/c-sharp-calculate-cpu-usage-for-a-specific-application)

Comment: Use [@shytikov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49064915/12031933) from the suggested duplicate to get per-process ID usages.